# Disable multi window feature programmatically

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, samsung-mobile-sdk, multi-window, android-window

[image]

I am trying to disable multi window feature of android. I have read the android documentation and know that resizeableActivity would only work for android N (API level 24) but I want to disable it on lower level android APIs. As Samsung devices have multi window feature on its all device (approx). So I have to disable it.

Comment: Samsung MultiWindow has different way to set! so why do you need to disable it?

Comment: I got this requirement for an enterprise application. So, I need to disable it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that in runtime. Your application either supports multi window mode, or it doesn't. Parameters, that are given in `AndroidManifest.xml` cannot be changed during runtime.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#configuring) of `android:resizeableActivity`:

> If this attribute is set to true, the activity can be launched in split-screen and freeform modes. If the attribute is set to false, the activity does not support multi-window mode. If this value is false, and the user attempts to launch the activity in multi-window mode, the activity takes over the full screen.

For specifically Samsung devices you can try putting this in manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable"
            android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.penwindow.enable" 
            android:value="false" />
```

Comment: @Awais, `I need to disable this feature on lower level also` that feature won't work on API lower than 24, which means it's disabled by default.

Comment: You don't need anything else then 'android:resizeableActivity="false"' and targetSdkVersion at least 24. Don't worry about "Attribute resizeableActivity is only used in API level 24 and higher". AndroidManifest never cause crash for version error, it dismiss attribute for lower versions

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I could only do so on the lollipop!!!
@Awais

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.context.getContentResolver(), multi_window_enabled", 0 );
```