# How can I disable multiwindow mode for app Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, multi-window, split-screen

By setting this **android:resizeableActivity="false"** flag just gives a message that "App may not work in split mode" . But the app still goes to the split screen mode. I used this tag like this

```
<application android:resizeableActivity="false" > ... </application>
```

MinSDKVersion - 24

I have tried many solution but didn't find any luck.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46603618/10279394

[Disable multi window feature programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905679/disable-multi-window-feature-programmatically)

How can i disable it ?

Comment: "I have tried many solution but didn't find any luck" is not helpful to the reader. You should list what you've tried. For example did you see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#resizeableActivity

Comment: To my understanding, you can't really block split-mode. To an app split-mode is just a smaller screen. If you are willing to block small screen devices you could try to alter the [minHeight/minWidth of layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window#layout) and see if that works for your use case.

Comment: Bear in mind that multiwindow cannot be disabled in all cases, such as the freeform multiwindow used on Chrome OS, Samsung DeX, etc. And there were plenty of scenarios where even if you tried opting out this way that you would still wind up operating in split-screen mode. However, having `android:resizeableActivity="false"` on the root activity of a task is blocking split-screen mode for me on a Pixel 4.

Comment: @CommonsWare i'm testing my app on Redmi Note 7 pro and i tried your way by having `android:resizeableActivity="false"` on the splash activity but no luck.

Comment: Perhaps Redmi's launcher is doing something like [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/12/multi-window-multi-instance-like-it-or-not.html). Or, perhaps Redmi [has enabled this developer toggle all the time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/20/multi-window-like-it-or-not-again.html). You might want to try testing on some other hardware to see what the behavior is. Overall, though, AFAIK you cannot completely avoid multi-window, or even just completely avoid split-screen mode.

Comment: Have noticed one telecom app on my A22s could not be used in multiwindow mode. Came up to this topic for a tech details how to disable app from launch in this mode. ```android:resizeableActivity="false"``` looks like a possible (temp) solution.